# how to get an instance of a middleware in ASP core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I registered the following middleware below

```cs
public class Surveyor
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public long BlockedAttacks { get; set; }

    public Surveyor(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Get User-Agent.
        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("user-agent", out var userAgent) &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userAgent))
        {
            if (userAgent.ToString().Contains("eye"))
            {
                BlockedAttacks++;
                context.Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/error");
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

I registered it like so in my Program.cs file

```
app.UseMiddleware<Surveyor>();
```

now I need to access `Surveyor` inside a Controller class, however adding it to the constructor does not work and it seems like not in the scope either, how do I proceed?

I tried adding it on the constructor of the Controller class where I need to access the `BlockedAttacks`  property on the middleware I wrote, I get an error.

Comment: Put the functionality you need from the Middleware into a separate class (service), register that service in DI  (most likely a singleton, since you seem to have some state (count)), then inject that into the middleware and the controller.

Comment: @Christian.K that looks like a good solution, I'll try it out